# Get ID of object added to inner collection on MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a user collection where each user contains a profile. Each profile can contain a list of email addresses that should be saved for that user. Using MongoDB, I can add an email to that list by doing:

```
db.users.update_one( {'_id': ObjectId(userid)}, {'$push': {'profile.emails': email.__dict__}} )
```

This will generate an `_id` for the email, which I want. However, as far as I can tell, the `UpdateResult` returned doesn't contain the `_id` of the newly added item. I know that since email addresses are unique, I could query against that value but I don't think I should have to perform a second request. Is there a way I can request this ID with the update request?

The email payload looks like this:

```
{
    'address': 'jdoe@fake.email.com',
    'is_primary': true,
    '_id': null
}
```

and the result of the request (retrieved from the server) is:

```
emails: [
    {
        'address': 'jdoe@fake.email.com',
        'is_primary': true,
        '_id': ObjectId("5d592f53d3f075f4acfdfab1")
    }
]
```

To be completely clear, the email dictionary does have a `_id` field so it's quite possible that it's being populated automatically by MongoDB.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data and also the `email` dictionary?
Because in strict MongoDB terms, doing a `$push` against an array should not generate an `_id`.

Comment: @Ptijohn I have done so. If you would like additional information, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really get my head around the `_id` generation, it should not be done by MongoDB.

Nevertheless, the `findOneAndUpdate` with the `returnNewDocument` option set to `true` should do the trick. Have a look over there : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

This will return the full document after being updated.

Comment: So, I think MongoDB automatically sets the `_id` field if it is present in the dictionary. However, in this case, the field is mutable rather than immutable. Just a coincidence I suppose.